# how to delete file from ftp disk in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, ftp

i using laravel ftp and i can upload file successfully

```
$this->path = $this->file->storePublicly( 'chats/' . $this->year . "/" . $this->month , 'ftp');
```

i try this to delete file from ftp storage with this codes but none of this not working

1. `Storage::disk('ftp')->exists('/files/chats/2021/4/VX9FzZ3votNThqEC1lVZKoo0bkY0VbcEyCEdYxFU.jpg')`
2. `$ftp = new Ftp([config array]);`
   `$ftp->delete('files/chats/2021/4/VX9FzZ3votNThqEC1lVZKoo0bkY0VbcEyCEdYxFU.jpg');`

in #1 method i see this error in cpanel Errors :

`2021-04-22 14:12:08.278499 [INFO] [10381] [195.201.169.252:47646:HTTP2-1#APVH_dl.pinpaper.ir:443] Auto Index is disabled for [/home/root/public_html/], access denied`.
I change file permission to 0777 and i see "access is denied" error

in #2 methos i got this error `ftp_delete(): Could not delete files/chats/2021/4/VX9FzZ3votNThqEC1lVZKoo0bkY0VbcEyCEdYxFU.jpg: No such file or directory`

bit i check cpanel and i see thw files with currect directory.

Comment: What does this mean? `in #1 method i got no error and just not working.` Did you receive an error message or error code or an exception? Check the FTP server logs for messages related to the delete command. Edit your question with details.

Comment: @JohnHanley i see access denied in cpanel errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i clear files from start of path it work properly. i dont know why this is happen, only its work. thank you dear [john hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley)

```
files/chats/2021/4/VX9FzZ3votNThqEC1lVZKoo0bkY0VbcEyCEdYxFU.jpg
```